# Implicit val from context case class

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-2.12

I have a case class:

```scala
case Context(tracker: Tracker)
```

I have a processor class with a get def, that expects an implicit parameter of Tracker defined as:

```scala
class Processor(){
    def get(id: String)(implicit tracker: Tracker): Unit
}
```

and I have my calling class:

```scala
class repo(process: Processor){
    def get(id: String)(implicit ctx : Context): Unit{
        process.get(id)
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way for my to map from context -> Tracker? I've been trying to use an implicit def in the companion of 'repo' but am still seeing 'no implicit val available' for the Tracker when calling process.get(id)

Comment: Do you control either `Context` or `Tracker`?

Comment: I control Context. I could be explicit, but if there is a way to support not being explicit I would rather that

Comment: @athomassi put the implicit conversion suggested by Dmytro on the companion object of `Context` it should work as expected.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Companion of `Tracker`, not `Context`

Comment: @DmytroMitin OP doesn't control `Tracker` only `Context`, I had understood that the source type of an implicit conversion is also searched, but thinking about it maybe it is too much for the compiler to search.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, I haven't noticed that OP's comment. Source type of an implicit conversion is searched but `ifContextThenTracker` is not implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define implicit in the scope

```
implicit def ifContextThenTracker(implicit c: Context): Tracker = c.tracker
```

> I've been trying to use an implicit def in the companion of 'repo' but am still seeing 'no implicit val available' for the Tracker when calling process.get(id)

Please see rules of implicit resolution in [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

You can put `ifContextThenTracker` into companion object of `Tracker` if you have access to it. Otherwise you can import implicit.

Comment: The problem is that it doesnt make c.tracker implicit within the context, and I wanted to avoid explicit calls as I like how clean implicits are.
Edit: Just saw your edit, checking now

Comment: @athomassi Please see update. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I added the implicit def to the context, and then imported the context and that worked. Much appreciated! =)

Comment: @athomassi If you put `ifContextThenTracker` into the companion of `Tracker` you don't have to import implicit, otherwise (if you put it into the companion of `Context`, companion of `repo` etc.) you'll have to.